# Killing an child process run through system() function in infinte loop is not working in perl

Tags: perl

I have tried with simple program of infinite loop, I ran it using PERL script and tried to KILL it after sleep of 10, but my program is not killing the child-process and runs in infinite loop.

//C CODE: 
   $cat loop.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

while(1){
 printf("Infinite loop\n");
        }

return 0;
}


$ gcc loop.c -o loop.bin
```

// PERL CODE 
    $cat timeout.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);

if(!defined( my $pid = fork())) {
die "Cannot fork a child: $!";
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
   print "Printed by child process\n";
   system("./loop.bin");
} else {
   print "Printed by parent process\n";
   sleep(10);
   my $ret = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);

   if ($ret == 0){
     kill ('KILL',$pid);
         sleep(1);
         }
   }
```

//OUTPUT: After execution the perl script is not killing the child process (./TC_1.bin)
    $ perl timeout.pl

```
Printed by child process
Infinite loop
Infinite loop
Infinite loop
Infinite loop
Infinite loop
Infinite loop
Infinite loop
Infinite loop
...
...
..
```

Comment: <pre> <code>#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void process_1()
{
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  if(fork() == 0)
  {
  printf( "child\n");
  }else{
  while(1){
  printf("parent\n");
  }
  }
}
int main()
{
   process_1();
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$pid` is the process id of the child process that was created by the `fork` call. It is a perl process. When you call `system($command)`, that creates a new process, running the command `$command`, and you don't know what the process id of that command is. Calling `kill('KILL',$pid)` sends a signal to the background perl process, but not necessarily to any of its children, so you can't be sure that the `system` call will also receive the signal.

One solution is to use `exec` instead of `system`.

```
...
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
   print "Printed by child process\n";
   exec("./loop.bin");
} else {
...
```

`exec` is like `system`, but instead of launching the command in a new process, it replaces the existing process with a process running the command, preserving the process id. So after calling `exec`, the child perl process will be gone, and `$pid` will refer to the process running the command `./loop.bin`. Now you can signal `$pid` and it will be sent to the desired process.

Comment: It is working with "exec" instead of "system". But in same test-case were we have multiple fork(), above perl script will not work. Can you suggest me, more improvement needed in above script.

Comment: Note: the question in the comment above was answered in a [follow up post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50450832/4653379)