# how to kill process having multiple fork using perl

Tags: perl

I have a test-case where multiple fork is used to create grandchild and the parent process is in infinite loop, I am implementing a perl script to kill the process. Currently it is working for single fork() but not for multiple fork():

TEST_CASE:
    $cat loop.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void process_1()
{
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  if(fork() == 0)
  {
  printf( "G_Child1\n");
  }else{
  while(1){
  printf("parent\n");
  }
  }
}
int main()
{
   process_1();
    return 0;
}
```

$ gcc loop.c -o loop.bin

PERL-SCRIPT: Script to run the above binary file. Below script is working fine for one fork() but not working with multiple fork():

$ cat timeout.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);

if(!defined( my $pid = fork())) {
die "Cannot fork a child: $!";
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
   print "Printed by child process\n";
  exec("./loop.bin");
} else {
   print "Printed by parent process\n";
   sleep(1);
   my $ret = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);

   if ($ret == 0){
     kill ('KILL',$pid);
         sleep(1);
         }
   }
```

OUTPUT:
     $perl timeout.pl

```
Printed by child process
G_Child1
parent
parent
parent
parent
parent
parent
parent
parent
.....
.....
.....
```

Comment: Do you realise that your four `fork` calls are executed by both the parent and the children, leaving a total of sixteen processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a more complicated case, you can set the perl child process to be a *session* *leader* with `POSIX::setsid()`, and then send the signal to the process group by passing a negative value to `kill`.

```
if(!defined( my $pid = fork())) {
    die "Cannot fork a child: $!";
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
    POSIX::setsid();        # make this process a session leader
    print "Printed by child process\n";
    system("./program_that_forks"); exit;  #  or exec('./program_that_forks')

} else {
    ...
    kill('KILL', -$pid);    #  -$pid means signal the whole process group
    ...
}
```

If the `program_that_forks` is also manipulating process groups, either by calling `setsid(1)` or by closing standard file descriptors and becoming a daemon, the convention is for the program to write its process id to a file, and for system task scripts to read this file to signal the program (run `ls /var/run/*.pid` to see some examples).

Comment: Instead of  system("./program_that_forks"); exit;    I am using Makefile to compile and execute the binary like "system("make clean all test -j8"); exit(0);". Sometime it work fine but sometime it  throws me error like gcc -O3 TC_1.c -lm -o TC_1.bin > TC_1.log
./TC_1.bin
make: execvp: ./TC_1.bin: Command not found
make: *** [TC_1.run] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gcc -O3 TC_2.c -lm -o TC_2.bin > TC_2.log

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a perl test in which I was forking into a subprocess that was running a new Java process also had three java descendent processes. So I had:

```
Perl test process (filename.t)
  - Perl fork
    - Java (main)
      - Java sub proc 1
      - Java sub proc 2
      - Java sub proc 3
```

The solution was killing the list of processes in ascending order, from descendents to ancestor. Actually, Java did allow me to kill the main process and will also kill the other three sub procs, but killing the second Perl process wouldn't stop the next java proc (the main).